# Auto-layout changing depending on view as setting on simulator

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I am noticing something strange using XCode 9.3.

I have a view with a UIToolBar on the bottom of it. I have set the following constraints:

1. Align Center X to: superview
2. Trailing Space (0): superview
3. Leading Space (0): superview
4. Equal Width: superview
5. Bottom Space (0): superview
6. Height equals 44.

The superview is a UIView.

When I viewAs iPhone 8 and then load an iPhone SE Simulator you can see the pink section on the image is where the toolbar is not satisfying rule 4 above.

[image: Toolbar width issue in SE simulator; viewAs: iPhone 8]

However, if I set viewAs iPhone SE, it works perfectly:

[image: Tollbar with NO width issue in SE Simulator; viewAs SE]

Any ideas anyone?

I've done no Vary for Traits.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? This just started happening to me, and I'm absolutely perplexed.

Comment: No not yet. I ended up getting someone else do re-do them all. I'd still like to know though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. For me, it turned out I was programmatically setting appearance stuff in viewDidLoad, before the right layout had been set or whatever. Your issue seems different though... Good luck, hope you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Trailing Space (0): superview

Leading Space (0): superview

Bottom Space (0): superview

Height equals 44.

You just need these 4 constraints

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't fix it. It does make the constraints simpler which is good but changing the viewAs still seems to be the issue.

Comment: Just one more thing, you are not adding constraints programmatically. right?